# Sub plot of 3D points (x, y, z) for each lat and long location on a map

Tags: r, rstudio, ggmap

I have about 50 pairs of Latitude and Longitude of locations within the Continental US and need to plot 3D points (x, y, z) with a line and an arrow for each location. I need to use R Studio because will do some analysis of the data once several routes are collected.

I can plot the locations on Excel maps but cannot add the sub plots for the 3D points.

Have not found code to combine the map and sub plot

I can plot the 3D points but cannot force the origin to be at each Lat & Long location to add a line and arrow. The map and sub plots will represent the readings of an accelerometer traveling across the US measuring G force to understand degree of impacts during the trip.

Comment: Have you looked at the choroplethr package? If you really want help with code here, you should provide something to work with.

Comment: Perhaps `mapdeck` would be appropriate here:   https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/trips.html

Comment: Jon Spring, thank you for the reply. I'll give mapdeck a try.

Comment: markhogue, understood. I'll add what I have come up with so far. Thank you for the reply.